# Change the order of execution of different directives throughout the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple interrelated directives (well it's just two actually). Is there any way to influence the order of the execution of their linking function?

```
<directive1>
    <directive2></directive2>
</directive1>
```

In this example directive1 is executed only after its child directive2, while I would have expected the parent to be executed first as it is further up the DOM. Is there any other way to manipulate the order of execution than using timeouts?

I tried using `priority` for the directive, but this only applies to several directives on the same element.

Comment: could try a `$broadcast` from parent directive... run child code when received with `$on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Angular Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope),

to send a message from a parent scope down to child scope, use scope.$broadcast

to send a message from a child scope to a parent scope, use the scope.$emit